# Package Tableau dashboard to display org data

Tags: reporting, integration, tableau

I understand that Tableau lives outside of Salesforce orgs but can access data from orgs and be embedded back into Salesforce using [widgets like this LWC component.](https://github.com/tableau/tableau-viz-lwc)

In my (managed) package I want to have a Dashboard that shows a diagram with relations of org specific data. Making this work for data objecs and for a single org is easy but I struggle with details of my requirement:

1. I want to report on `Metadata & Tooling API objects`. I can't see many of them because Tableau Desktop uses an **old API version**. But I need Summer'20 / v.49
2. For such objects the Live data option is disabled and **only Extract works**. I want near-live data. How can I get this with Extract only tables? Can I schedule (each day) such an extract?
3. How can I build and share **a Tableau viz that is generic** and can be used in arbitrary org in which my app is installed to? I would expect the Tableau dashboard embedded into Salesforce first ask the user to `OAuth` with his own org .

Comment: #3 - On SF side this is just like any other 3rd party integration. Provide a way for admin of the subscriber org to configure connectivity to 3rd party service, select assets, render assets, etc. On Tableau side - have a look at https://tableau.github.io/embedding-playbook

Comment: @identigral a comment which only will be understood that already have the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

For 2, you can schedule refreshes of your extract using Tableau Online or Server: https://help.tableau.com/current/online/en-us/schedule_add.htm
You can set it up to be hourly/daily etc.

And for the last question, once you created the Tableau viz, you can use the [Document API](http://tableau.github.io/document-api-python/) to update the connection. You will also need the [REST API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api.htm) to download the workbook. Another option is to use [Tableau Tools](https://github.com/bryantbhowell/tableau_tools/).

Cheers,
Gigi

Comment: What about question part 1?

Comment: I reached out to the team and they should be updating to the latest API version in Tableau 2020.4

Comment: Any ETA for that version?